# Why do I have to convert to degrees to calculate length here? Why do some equations require converting?

Tags: geometry

I'm reviewing for the fundamentals of engineering exam, and I'm stuck on this question. This is a problem about a regular polygon with 6 sides, and it asks to calculate the apothem r which is the normal distance from the center to one of the sides.

What is it that requires me to convert to degrees, and how do I know in which cases to convert to degrees?

Why would a calculation in rad not give me the length of the apothem?

Something this simple shouldn't be slowing me down...[click here to see the picture which is essential for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz2fT.jpg)

Please see this picture for the actual problem and solution given by Mr. Lindenburg

Comment: While the problem can be solved by converting to degrees, it is not necessary.  Just replace $60^\circ$ by $\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

You do  not have to convert to degrees.

In this case obviously you are talking about $\pi/3$ or $\pi/6$ which are well behaved angles.

I do not know why the author is using decimal values for  $\pi/3$  and $\pi/6$ to make it look awkward and then convert to degrees to look more decent.